# What is causing this behavior, in our C# DateTime type?

Tags: c#

```
[Test]
public void Sadness()
{
   var dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
   Assert.That(dateTime, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.Parse(dateTime.ToString())));
}
```

Failed :

```
 Expected: 2011-10-31 06:12:44.000
 But was:  2011-10-31 06:12:44.350
```

I wish to know what is happening behind the scenes in ToString() etc to cause this behavior.

EDIT After seeing Jon's Answer :

```
[Test]
public void NewSadness()
{
    var dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    Assert.That(dateTime, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.Parse(dateTime.ToString("o"))));
}
```

Result :

```
Expected: 2011-10-31 12:03:04.161
But was:  2011-10-31 06:33:04.161
```

Same result with capital and small 'o' . I'm reading up the docs, but still unclear.

Comment: Adding `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` did not help : it produced `Expected: 2011-10-31 12:09:51.928
  But was:  2011-10-31 06:39:51.928
`

Comment: Some Parsing logic / to string logic added 6 hours and 30 minutes to the time :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default format specifier is "G" - the general-purpose format - which has limited fidelity. If you want to reproduce **exactly** the same thing, use the roundtrip specifier, "O".

```
string s = dateTime.ToString("O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Assert.That(dateTime, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.ParseExact(
       s, "O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind)));
```

Comment: I edited my question, incorporating your idea - and the result is weird, Im still puzzled

Comment: @Zasz why is the result weird? If *adds* to the confusion that you have "expected" and "actual" the wrong way around in your test... is that all we mean here?

Comment: @Zasz try also using `DateTime.Parse(s, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind)`

Comment: @Zasz to emphasise - it is important to ensure the parse knows it is expecting round-trip

Comment: Good call on the need for RoundtripKind. I've just tried it, and it *is* required in order to properly roundtrip. That's pretty bizarre given that it's present in the formatted string. Weird.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at what `dateTime.ToString()` produces - it will typically only be accurate to the second, although it depends on cultural settings. If `ToString()` only gives a result accurate to a second, there's no way that parsing the string can give more information...

You can use the "o" [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) to provide a round-trippable string representation. For example, at the moment it produces something like:

```
2011-10-31T06:28:34.6425574Z
```

EDIT: You need to parse with the same specifier to get the same result back:

```
string text = dateTime.ToString("o");
// Culture is irrelevant when using the "o" specifier
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "o", null,
                                      DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

Comment: +1. Zasz, please READ the MSDN article Jon linked to, especially "o" and "u" formats. There is detailed explanation how to acheve roundtrip.